# Extract Float Values from Strings with Conditions in Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, data-manipulation

I have the following dataframe of people with their test results:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': 'A B C D E F G H I J'.split(),
                   'result': [0.30, '<0.30', '0.20', 1.20, 'less than 0.30', 'less than 0.25', 1.26, 'test 1.29', 'less than 3.30', 'more than 0.40']})

print(df)

  name          result
0    A             0.3
1    B           <0.30
2    C            0.20
3    D             1.2
4    E  less than 0.30
5    F  less than 0.25
6    G            1.26
7    H       test 1.29
8    I  less than 3.30
9    J  more than 0.40
```

I need to extract float values from `result` column, for which I'm applying the following code:

```
df['result'] = df['result'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)').astype('float')
```

However, there is a problem. I have a threshold of `0.30`. That means I need to keep the rows with the result of `0.30` or more than `0.30`. With this logic, the result with `less then 30` or `<30` should be omitted. That's why `df[df['result'] >= 0.30]` won't work when I apply the filter.

```
 name   result
0   A   0.3
1   B   0.30 # should be omitted as it's less than 0.30
3   D   1.2
4   E   0.30 # should be omitted as it's less than 0.30
6   G   1.26
7   H   1.29
8   I   3.3  
9   J   0.40
```

**Desired output:**

```
  name  result
0   A   0.30
3   D   1.20
6   G   1.26
7   H   1.29
8   I   3.30
9   J   0.40
```

What would be the smartest way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to keep the values that are strictly greater than 0.30, then you should be using "greater than" (`>`), and not "greater than or equal to" (`>=`), don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend transforming the data before applying any additional logic. To do this, I'd add two new columns `min` and `max`. By doing it this way you'll get a couple of benefits:

1. It's non-destructive, which will make it easier to debug down the line.
2. By converting the `less than`, `<`, etc to a standardized version early, it becomes easier for logic downstream. Which will prevent large refactoring if a new 'rule' appears in the data (e.g. someone types `greater than`)

The regex is doing a lot of the heavy lifting, if you could find a parser to handle the `greater/less` text it'd most likely be a little more robust than the simple regex I wrote.

It looks a little more complicated than it really is, most of it is just named groups:

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NdpY13/1)

**Regex Explanation**

```
(?P<operator>                            - named group for the text prefix
 (?P<lessOrGreater>less|more)\s+than     - looks for `less than` or `more than`
 |\<|\>                                  - OR `<` or `>`
 |.+                                     - Otherwise capture all characters prior to the num
)?                                       - the operator named group is optional (e.g. when it's just a number)
\s*                                      - optional whit espace between operator and number
(?P<num>\d+\.\d+)                        - capture number. Can't handle `,` yet.
```

**Python Code**

Python/Pandas isn't what I code in daily, so I'm sure there's a better way to code this up, but below is a naive solution that should get you going.

```
import pandas as pd
import re


def addMinMax(df):
    simpleParser = re.compile('(?P<operator>(?P<lessOrGreater>less|more)\\s+than|\\<|\\>|.+)?\\s*(?P<num>\\d+\\.\\d+)')
    min = []
    max = []
    abs_min = 0
    abs_max = 1  # could also use null if you prefer unbounded.
    increments = 0.001  # using this to move anything less/greater one step away.

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        result = str(row['result'])

        match = simpleParser.search(result)

        operator = match.group('operator')
        less_or_greater = match.group('lessOrGreater')
        num = float(match.group('num'))

        # no operator means there was no text prior to the number, so it should be equal to
        if operator is None:
            min.append(num)
            max.append(num)
            
        # check for less
        elif (less_or_greater is not None and less_or_greater == 'less') or operator == '<':
            min.append(abs_min)
            max.append(num - increments)
        
        # check for greater
        elif (less_or_greater is not None and less_or_greater == 'more') or operator == '<':
            min.append(num + increments)
            max.append(abs_max)
            
        # if we're not sure, assume equal but print a warning.
        else:
            print(f'UNKNOWN INPUT: `{result}`. Assuming equal to `{num}`.')
            min.append(num)
            max.append(num)

    df['min_result'] = min
    df['max_result'] = max


df = pd.DataFrame({'name': 'A B C D E F G H I J'.split(),
                   'result': [0.30, '<0.30', '0.20', 1.20, 'less than 0.30', 'less than 0.25', 1.26, 'test 1.29',
                              'less than 3.30', 'more than 0.40']})

addMinMax(df)

print('\nEntire Dataset with new columns:\n')
print(df)

print('\n\nFilter to items greater than or equal to .3:\n')
print(df[df['min_result'] >= 0.30])
```

**Sample Output**

```
UNKNOWN INPUT: `test 1.29`. Assuming equal to `1.29`.

Entire Dataset with new columns:

  name          result  min_result  max_result
0    A             0.3       0.300       0.300
1    B           <0.30       0.000       0.299
2    C            0.20       0.200       0.200
3    D             1.2       1.200       1.200
4    E  less than 0.30       0.000       0.299
5    F  less than 0.25       0.000       0.249
6    G            1.26       1.260       1.260
7    H       test 1.29       1.290       1.290
8    I  less than 3.30       0.000       3.299
9    J  more than 0.40       0.401       1.000


Filter to items greater than or equal to .3:

  name          result  min_result  max_result
0    A             0.3       0.300        0.30
3    D             1.2       1.200        1.20
6    G            1.26       1.260        1.26
7    H       test 1.29       1.290        1.29
9    J  more than 0.40       0.401        1.00

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Best of luck on your problem.